# firefox jquery ajax cross site

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I have the following jQuery ajax code that works fine in IE, Chrome and Opera. However, in Firefox it is aborted (calls remote computer but the remote computer says there's a "handshake problem").

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
 jQuery.support.cors = true;      
    $.ajax({
       url: "tlscheck.site.com:10443/a/check",
       type: "GET",
       crossDomain: true,
       success: function (json) {
          UpdateDatabaseForTLSVersion(json);
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, status, strErr) {
          //alert("Error: " + status);
          //alert(strErr);
       }
    });      
});
```

I already have the host headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*", etc set. And the server supports CORS (that's how IE and Chrome are getting there)...

Any ideas?